# when open on emulator, the gradation is not smooth visually

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout, android-studio-3.0

I have a gradation like below. [image]

but the problem is when I see this on emulator (Android Studio Emulator)

it`s not very smooth it seems like very layered (photo below)

[image]

my programming language is flutter and android

why is this happening? how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses a low-quality renderer so that it runs fast enough especially on less powerful hardware. Test it out on a real device and you'll likely see better results. I believe you may also be able to bump up the graphics on the emulator but not 100% sure if that would improve this. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html).

Comment: thanks it seems working I changed HARDWARE GLES 2.0 to SOFTWARE GLES 2.0 in emulator configuration

Comment: Happy to hear that Marsho